# Identify spawned processes

Tags: linux, monitoring, process

I think that the number of processes forked per sec is a bit too high on one of the servers. How can I monitor what processes are spawned? Is there any tool that can help me? I know I can `strace` a specific process looking for `fork()`, but is there something similar that works system-wide?

I'd like to know at least the pid (and name) and it's ppid (and name of the parent).

I mean realtime monitoring of new `fork()`s, not a snapshot of what's available now.

Answer (score 0):

> I think that the number of processes forked per sec is a bit too high
>   on one of the servers

I don't think so. As my understanding, all the child processes will be forked when the parent process starting. So, it's not too many as you think.

> How can I monitor what processes are spawned?

You can do it by combination of `ps` and `watch` command ([paging version](https://serverfault.com/questions/50772/is-there-a-paging-version-of-watch)):

```
watch 'ps -eo ppid,pid,comm --forest'
```

Comment: On the system I was having issues with, the fork rate is constantly around 60+ per second. Services running there don't pre-fork worker children. Additionally the spawned processes seem to get killed so fast they're hard to catch on ps (let alone a `watch`ed ps)

Comment: If it be killed so fast, then, AFAIK, there is no way, except `strace`.