# Command to monitor which processes have a given file open

Tags: monitoring, lsof

I know I can use `lsof path/to/file` to see which processes currently have a given file open.

Is there a `top`-like command I can use to continuously monitor which processes have a given file open?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of lsof, I would suggest using [fuser(1)](http://linux.die.net/man/1/fuser), especially since you say you want to watch for processes, and not ports or users or anything else.

Answer (score 6):

Take a look the `+|-r` option for repeat mode:

```
$ lsof -r 1 path/to/file
```

You can also use the [`watch`](https://serverfault.com/questions/50772/is-there-a-paging-version-of-watch) command:

```
$ watch -n 1 'lsof path/to/file'
```